# Url Redirect Parent page to a sub page

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

How do i write a particular htaccess redirect rule for the following scenario of directing a parent page to one of it's child pages?

if i request

http://mysite.mycompany.com/web 
then it should go 
http://mysite.mycompany/web/design-vision

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out its..

```
RewriteEngine On
RedirectMatch 301 ^/web/?$ http://mysite.mycompany/web/design-vision/
RewriteRule ^web/?$ http://mysite.mycompany/web/design-vision/ [R=301,L]
```